# How to view data saved with a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, spyder

I have downloaded an Apple stock price timeseries dataset and loaded it into a `pandas` `DataFrame`. However, I don't see the object in Spyder's Variable Explorer. Where is it saved?

In any case, I would like to view the data.

```
import pandas as pd
import ystockquote as ys
aapl = ys.get_historical_prices("aapl", "2010-01-01", "2015-01-01")
data = pd.DataFrame(aapl)  

>>> data
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 6 entries, Adj Close to Volume
Columns: 1258 entries, 2010-01-04 to 2014-12-31
dtypes: object(1258)
```

For some reason, the data doesn't display. Does the object not appearing in the Variable Explorer have anything to do with this issue?

Comment: "isn't saved in the Variable Explorer on the Python Spyder IDE", didnt get you there. Could you add some more info.

Comment: If you run the code I put in my question and run it. The variable "data" does not show up in the Variable Explorer.

Comment: In R/Matlab, if you create a variable. x=5;. The variable is saved in your workspace.

Comment: the data is there just the explorer doesnt support it so, it wouldnt show it . uncheck "exclude
unsupported data types".
in the explorer option.

Comment: looking for that option."exclude unsupported data types".

Comment: by the way, why is that when I type "data" I get <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 6 entries, Adj Close to Volume
Columns: 1258 entries, 2010-01-04 to 2014-12-31
dtypes: object(1258)       Instead of the data displaying???

Comment: that actually depends on the __str__ method of the DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

To print the first `N` rows, try:

```
data.head(N)
```

For more information, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html).

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder dev here*) Support for Pandas DataFrames was added in Spyder **2.3.1**, so I suppose you are using a version older than that.

Spyder latest version is **2.3.8**, so I encourage you to update to that version. It also fixes some problems with Series not showing in our Variable Explorer for Pandas 0.17.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the data frame variable in variable explorer
Uncheck "exclude unsupported data types" in the variable explorer's option

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could work. Try adding a **str** method to the ur class and in that method show the data you want to show.
eg

```
class Frame(DataFrame):

   def __str__(self):
       return self.as_matrix()
```

so this could show the matrix in the data explorer. this will only work if the data explorer uses the standard string representation of unknown types.